# WSGIScriptAlias does but WSGIScriptAliasMatch DOES NOT regard DirectoryIndex

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

this is my a.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/
rather than edit httpd.conf i simply work with a.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
DirectoryIndex 1
DocumentRoot /a/b/
ServerName domain.tld
WSGIScriptAlias /1 /a/1.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /2 /a/2.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

in this example if i go to domain.tld via web..

```
WSGIScriptAlias /1 /a/1.wsgi
```

is automatically executed.

but let's get rid of WSGIScriptAlias and use WSGIScriptAliasMatch instead.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DirectoryIndex 1
DocumentRoot /a/b/
ServerName domain.tld
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(.*) /a/$1.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

now.. when i go to domain.tld via web.. i do not see 1.wsgi
instead it is the default apache welcome page.

so looks like..

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(.*) /a/$1.wsgi
```

is not paying any attention to

```
DirectoryIndex 1
```

in other words via web domain.tld/1 works but domain.tld does not..

what is causing this ?

how is it that

```
WSGIScriptAlias /1 /a/1.wsgi
```

can interpret domain.tld as domain.tld/1 given the DirectoryIndex 1
but..

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(.*) /a/$1.wsgi
```

can not interpret domain.tld as domain.tld/1 given the DirectoryIndex 1 
?

once i solve this issue i plan on ensuring only numbers 1 to 99 are accepted and directed to wsgi scripts.

in other words.. domain.tld/1  (index) to domain.tld/99 which would point to 99.wsgi

in other words i understand (.*) might be a security issue.. but first i want to solve the issue of why.. DirectoryIndex is not being regarded.. by WSGIScriptAliasMatch.. when it is regarded just fine by 
WSGIScriptAlias

if i fail to solve this problem.. i will have to use perhaps 99 lines of..

```
WSGIScriptAlias /1 /a/1.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /2 /a/2.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /3 /a/3.wsgi
...
WSGIScriptAlias /99 /a/99.wsgi
```

in a.conf

which might be less logical.

all because DirectoryIndex would not work with WSGIScriptAliasMatch as it does with WSGIScriptAlias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(.+) /a/$1.wsgi
```

You are matching '/', and mapping it to '/a/.wsgi'. Ensure there is at least one character after the '/' and better still perhaps ensure they are numbers if that is the scheme you are going to use.

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/([1-9][0-9]*) /a/$1.wsgi
```